# Best ways to earn money

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I just got access to the clothing store in lumios city but everything is so expensive. the shirts are 100,000 and I only have 400,000. how can you earn money I know you can vs the league but are there any other good ways to get money?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, at *Restaurant Le Wow* in Lumiose City.

Bring a couple of pokemon and an amulet coin for more money. Tell the waiter that you want to try the Double Meal Battle, and you will fight 5 trainers, where your pokemon are healed after each trainer.

You can also use an O-Power here to get even more money.

A more descriptive guide can be found [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/1olev8/guide_how_to_make_quick_money_elite_4_alternative/).